# How can I split and parse dict-like string?

Tags: python

I have strings like this `"Parent(Parent1(Child1,Child2),Parent2(Child3,Child4))"`

Could you please show me *pythonic* way to convert it to dict `{"Parent": {"Parent1": ["Child1", "Child2"], "Parent2": ["Child3", "Child4"]}}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you can do some hacky things to get it working. But the most failsafe is probably to write a (context-free) *parser*.

Comment: Me thinks you'll need some regex. Unfortunately, I don't know regex well enough off the top of my head to help with that. Actually, maybe iterating through the string & keeping track of key characters (like ( ) and , )

Comment: regex is not very good with nesting. Maybe new regex module...

Comment: When reading questions like this, I somehow always substitute *pythonic* with *magic* in my head.

Comment: Not magic, but optimal.

Comment: Start with json.loads and work your way from there. @ChristianKönig lol

Comment: @AdamOwczarczyk how I can use json.load to not json-like object?

Comment: json.loads, not json.load. json.loads takes string as an input. Once you load it, you can convert lists to dictionaries etc, whatever format you need.

Comment: I've got this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it won't work without preparsing. Tried to fiddle with it for like 5 minutes without result. Either use something like ast, or give up and ask your source provider for a reasonable format.